# Layout for Android Application on TV

Tags: android, xml, layout, television

I am designing an application for TV. When I load my application to TV screen, I see it still has the sizes of a smartphone. I have been playing with different dpi's but not working. Spent a day on this.

What are the steps to design the layout so that it will fit the TV screen?

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logimgdesc"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="@string/start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="@string/download" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spyonme"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spyonme"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnLoadFP"
        android:text="@string/stop" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is it doing? What do you want it to do? Did you read this? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: How are you communicating between the tv and the mobile? wifi,uart?

Comment: @twaddington, it looks like that document will be useful. I will have a look. Thank you.

user1092042, I have an intermediate device that runs android and connects to TV via HDMI. I am doing WIFI debugging.

Comment: @twaddington, I can accept your answer if you add it below. It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to implement support for multiple-screen sizes. I'd suggest you read the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) guide on the Android developer site.